# Find the CDF and use it to find all the medians

Tags: probability, self-study, density-function, cumulative-distribution-function, median

Show that for every $p$, $0\leq p\leq 1$, the function $f(x)$ = $p*sin(x) +(1-p)*cos(x)$, $0\leq x \leq \pi/2 $, and $f(x)=0$ otherwise, is a density function. Find its CDF and use it to find all the medians.

I was able to prove it a density function and also was able to get the CDF which is 
$(p +\sin(x) -p(\sin(x) + \cos(x))$ ; $0\leq x \leq \pi/2$ and $1$ for $ x\geq \pi/2$ and $zero$ elsewhere.
(I hope I am correct)

I don't understand the last part. What do they mean by finding all the medians?

Comment: It means to derive a formula that is valid for any $p$, like a median$(p)$ function. You know that the median of Uniform$(a,b)$ is $(b-a)/2$. Do the same for your situation.

Comment: You probably should add the self study tag.

Comment: I still can't figure it out. If I put it equal to 0.5, I have an equation with two variable p and x. How can I solve this?

Comment: Solve for $x$ to get the value that is the median. Write $x$ as a function of $p$. And, yes, self-study rag, please.

Comment: Cross-posted at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3505774/find-the-cdf-and-use-it-to-find-all-the-medians.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First median is defined where $F(x)=0.5$. Right now you have a CDF that is defined in terms of $p$ and $x$ and it is possible to define the median in terms of $p$(I did not check if your CDF is correct or not since it is your task). You can think of $p$ as a parameter and thus no need to worry if you have a definition that have $p$ in it

Comment: I can't solve the equation when I am equating it to 0.5
I tried substitution $sin$$ x=t$ but still nothing.